# XdbCollectionUnavailable exception : The HTTP response was not successful:Not Found

Tags: xdb, xconnect, xdb-cloud

We have an Azure Sitecore 10.3 setup to which we have added an additional CD app service which is on a different region. For the sites hosted in this app service, the XDB functionalities are not working whereas it's working for sites hosted on the CD app which comes with Sitecore default setup. From the logs, we could see the `**XdbCollectionUnavailableexception : the HTTP response was not successful: NotFound (screenshot attached).**`

We have verified the certificate thumbprint in configs and app service configuration and all seems correct. Can anyone help with this issue?[image]

Comment: Are you able to confirm the identify that the CD site is running under has access to the private key for the certificate? In VM/IIS setup you can do this via MMC, but not sure with app service.

Answer (score 1):

The Configuration Strings in Azure for WebApp services rely on https url's that map to the xConnect Services for various roles.

If you open up the ConnectionStrings.config on one of the CD's that are working, you'll find what these URL's are.

In order for the CD in the other region to be able to see xConnect it's going to need network security rules in place to allow that connection, and possibly even DNS services to resolve the hostname.

Once this is done, you are most likely going to run into a Certificate Issue, as you'll need to make sure the new CD's in the second region have access to the same Certificate for xConnect that's represented in the ConnectionStrings.config Thumbprint.

The error message you are getting is indicating that the AppService is not able to resolve and/or connect to the xConnect Collection Service.

You'll probably need to add a Virtual Gateway between the two regions' networks and ensure that there's network connectivity.

This will also include making sure that the hostname can be resolved.